# What is a better base for skid foundation, gravel or crushed stone?

Tags: foundation, gravel

Building a skid foundation for a shed. What is the best material to put under the skids for stability/leveling. Uniform gravel (like [this](http://www.sakrete.com/products/detail.cfm/prod_alias/All-Purpose-Gravel)) or crushed stone like a 5/8 minus?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Tamped gravel uniform or not, big or small, rounded or jagged with thin concrete pads (home-made or store bought), retaining wall caps or path pavers set into the gravel. Like doing a walking path really. You can even do a peanut brittle type setup by pouring in a lot of real soupy cement. But, the 4-inch carve-out of the ground you'll do should retain the gravel quite well.

Comment: I read that a material with a wide range of stone sizes locks together better. Making a more stable base. Is this not true/relevant?

Comment: Yeah, there's plenty to read alright & most of it I & the real world laugh at. Tamping is your real friend, you want the half-full bag of full potato chips, not the abused bag that's got some full chips left but is mostly crumbs. Much better freeze & thaw, water drainage, nothing migrates, nothing washes out & it's better looking.

Comment: With rock you want to lock together never use river rock used crushed quarried rock or shale it will lock together where river rock moves every time it is walked on.

Comment: I totally agree, I was just saying use pretty much any gravel you want, nothing about river rock. His uniform gravel example is the sort of rounded I was referring to. Tamping is the really important part & regardless of gravel choice any & all kinds will move easily. In this version of his shed plan it's just a gravel bed situation & he can skip the gravel altogether to put some pads on dirt.